# Xamarin. How to create ListView with rectangular colored buttons with two lines of text and image aside?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Simple example of what I mean:

[image]

I don't see any properties of Button object to make it.

Maybe I have to use another object instead of Button?

Comment: You don't have to use button at all. You can use any kind of Layout and then give it an onClickListener.

Comment: Could just use an image with a green tick and a red x and when clicked toggle the images.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı, thank you! I will post here my solution later.

Comment: Which approach are you using ? Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can style all of it by creating custom cell for ListView

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/